# symfony get selected choiceType value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

hi i'm working on symfony 3.3 project. I have a form with choiceType and i wonder what is the correct way to read the selected option

code of controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('decision', ChoiceType::class, array('choices'  => array(
        'valider' => 'valider',
        'rejeter' => 'rejeter',
    )

    ))
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('validerRejeter', array('id' => $cours->getId())))
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->getForm();

  $form->handleRequest($request); 
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
  {
    $choix=$request->request->get('form');
    if ($choix == 'valider')
        $cours->setEtat('publié');
    else 
        $em->remove($cours);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$choix = $form->get('decision')->getData();
```

or

```
$choix = $request->request->get('decision');
```